# How can I compute an exact (integer) determinant in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, matrix, hmatrix

I wanted to use [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) but it insists on `Double` and this gives rounding errors sometimes. Looking at the source, I tried

```
type instance DoubleOf Rational = Rational
```

but `DoubleOf` is not exported (`Numeric.ContainerBool` is hidden), and that's probably for a reason.

Comment: Have you tried [this numeric matrix package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bed-and-breakfast)? Apparently it claims to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform exact operations on matrices using [`bed-and-breakfast` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bed-and-breakfast).

Here's sample ghci session:

```
>>> import Numeric.Matrix
>>> import Data.Ratio
>>> let m = fromList [[1 % 2, 2 % 3], [3 % 4, 4 % 5]] :: Matrix Rational
>>> det m
(-1) % 10
>>> m * m
 3 % 4  13 % 15
 39 % 40  57 % 50

>>> m^4
 563 % 400  819 % 500
 7371 % 4000  10723 % 5000
```

Comment: but the package (version 0.4.3 from hackage) does not compile with ghc-7.8.2 (`‘typeOf’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Typeable’`)

Comment: I guess they just haven't uploaded a fresh version to hackage yet.